# How do I print the last query executed in Yii php framework?

Tags: php, yii

This is my code:

```
$ptoRequests = CalendarRequest::model()
                    ->with(array('intervals'))
                    ->findAll(array('order' => 't.time, t.id desc',
                'condition' => 'eventId in (5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11) and statusId in (1,2) and userId = "' . $user->userId . '" and (intervals.enddate >= :from)',
                'params' => array('from' => date("Y-m-d"))));
                echo "<pre>"; var_dump($ptoRequests->getQuery()); echo "</pre>"; exit();
```

What I want to achieve is to print the last query executed. The getQuery() function returns me a fatal error. What should I do ? Thx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21231729/yii-echo-the-last-query On this github page:  https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/1173, you can see developers bounced your specific functionality at the moment is was requested

Comment: I tried with logs but the application.log file is empy

Comment: I am no YII pro.. But could it be the with() function is not satified in the model and therefor no query has been made?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
echo ModelClassName::model()->
getCommandBuilder()->
createFindCommand('table_name', $criteria)->text;
```

where $criteria is

```
$criteria= new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->condition="your query condition";
$criteria->order="t.time desc"
```

check CDbCriteria [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria) for reference