# how to get last sql in yii?

Tags: php, sql, yii

If I don't use yii debug tool in yii 1.x . Is there anyway to get last sql after querying?

Comment: show at the following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21231729/yii-echo-the-last-query

Comment: You need to enable yii logging feature.