# Getting last executed query in Yii

Tags: yii

In Laravel, this is simple:

```
$queries = DB::getQueryLog();
$last_query = end($queries);
```

How can I see the last full query executed in Yii 1.1?

Most of my code is executed from the commandline, so enabling profiling and logging in a way that shows the output on the bottom of the page is not useful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Yii - echo the last query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21231729/yii-echo-the-last-query)

Comment: I'm running from commandline, so displaying output at bottom of page is not useful.