# Yii2: How to log SQL query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, debugging, logging, yii2

I want to log every SQL query executed so I can debug it and then copy, paste and test it in my database tool.

I tried this solution ([Yii - echo the last query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21231729/yii-echo-the-last-query)) (and other similar solutions) but it is not working because I think it is for **Yii1**. I need it for **Yii2**.

I think the solution is independent of the database (I use PostgreSQL).
Maybe I have to configure it in the `common/config/main-local` file.

Comment: did you try anything from https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-logging ?

Answer (score 5):

If you need in Yii (1), please update your components array in main.php like this

```
       'components'=>array(
    #/*
                        'fixture'=>array(
                                'class'=>'system.test.CDbFixtureManager',                
                        ),
            #*/
                        'db'=>array(
                                'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=intakes_manager_test',
                                'emulatePrepare' => true,
                                'username' => 'root',
                                'password' => 'root',
                                'charset' => 'utf8',
                                'enableProfiling'=>true,
            'enableParamLogging'=>true,
                        ),
                        'log'=>array(
                                'class'=>'CLogRouter',
                                'routes'=>array(
                                        array(
                                                'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                                                'levels'=>'error,trace,info,warning',
                                                //'filter'=>'CLogFilter',
                    'categories'=>'system.db.*',
                    'logFile'=>'sql.log'
                                        )
                                )
                        ),
         ),
```

For the same in Yii 2, do like below

```
'components' => [
        'log' => [
            'targets' => [
                'file' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                ],
                'db' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\DbTarget',
                ],
            ],
        ],
```

to know more about yii 2 logging see doc [here](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-logging)

Answer (score 0):

postgresql.conf

## log_min_duration_statement = -1    # -1 is disabled, 0 logs all statements

log_min_duration_statement = 0

You would need to restart the Postgresql service